# How can I show formatted text in textarea, if it is empty?

Tags: jquery, haml

How can I show text, using jQuery (with ul li p...), after focus is losed, and textarea is empty, now when I get focus I loose text, but how to show it if I didn't entered anything? 
My "pseudo placeholder" looks like this:

```
$('textarea.hinted').focus(function() {
    console.log('focus');
    $('#textarea-placeholder').hide();
});
$('textarea.hinted').blur(function() {
    console.log('blur');
    $('#textarea-placeholder').hide();
});
$('textarea.hinted').focusout(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if (this.val == '') {
        $('#textarea-placeholder').show(); 
    }
});
```

html

Comment: The title is very confusing. If there is no content, why would you want to format anything?

Comment: What I understand here is you want to show the content of a texatarea when it's empty? What's the goal?

Comment: confusing question... maybe you need something like a searchbox? where the search text disappears if you focus and appears again if nothing is in this input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('textarea.hinted').focusout(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('#textarea-placeholder').show(); 
    }
});
```

should work,

you should also probably remove the blur even as they are effectively the same thing (i believe)